# Trouble with initiating a saved Python program with command prompt

Tags: windows, command-prompt, python-2.5

I am trying to start a simple beginner's Python (2.5) program with this code, verbatim:

```
print('hello')
```

The file is saved as 'hello.py' in 'C:\Pythonpractice'.

I believe that thus far I am correct in my process.

So I go to my command prompt, type in what follows to try to get the program to run and I get this:

```
C:\Pythonpractice>hello.py
  File "C:\Pythonpractice\hello.py", line 1
    Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
 on win32
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am using IDLE and I have added Python to my PATH.  What am I missing here?  Is the invalid syntax referring to my Python code or my cmd entry?

Comment: Perhaps you've accidentally saved the file in Unicode rather than ANSI?  What text editor are you using?

Comment: I am entirely new to this, completely green, so I'm not sure if the following is going to answer your question.  I saved it as a .py file and I am using IDLE.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I spent some time playing with what you did and analyzing your error report, and have found what is undoubtedly your problem.

So lets look at the error report:

```
  File "C:\Pythonpractice\hello.py", line 1
    Python 2.5.4 (r254:67916, Dec 23 2008, 15:10:54) [MSC v.1310 32 bit (Intel)]
 on win32
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The first line is the location of the crash (file and line).

Now when I first looked at line 2 (which in this case is wrapped onto line 3) of the report, I was thinking it was telling me your system, but then I realized that python does not do that, and what it was showing, was the line of code that caused the crash. Now that's not your code.

IDLE has two modes, the first, is the shell:

The shell is a live response mode, where you type a line, hit enter and it runs it.

```
>>> print('hello')
hello
>>>
```

You type your command `print('hello')` after the `>>>` and it runs it and gives the output `hello` then waits for another command `>>>`.

The secound is the code editor, where you type code, save it, and run it.

Now your problem is that you ended up in the shell, and not in the code editor.

So your solution is to open the code editor, by opening the "File" menu on the top left; and clicking on: "New Window".

BTW: as a shortcut instead of using the cmd, you can just press F5 while in the code editor, and it will run what is open.

Sorry that was so long, but I felt that it would better help you, if I fully explained the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try `python hello.py` if PATH is properly configured.

Comment: This did not work either.  Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: can you copy-paste you EXACT code and run it [**here**](https://repl.it/languages/Python) to see if it works

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if you have some weird indentation on that line. I have nothing else for you, my friend.